# grey screen Appears before the tab page loads again

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an application where , the landing page is Tabs page with four "supertabs" . In the `<ion-navbar>` I have a button that navigates the app to a Search page.

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>App name </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only id="btnSearchNow" (click)="searchMyName()">
            <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>

<super-tabs scrollTabs="true" id="mainTabs" selectedTabIndex="0">
  <super-tab [root]="tab1Root" title="tab1"  [rootParams]="params1" ></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab2Root" title="tab2" [rootParams]="params2" ></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab3Root" title="tab3" [rootParams]="params3" ></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab4Root" title="tab4"   [rootParams]="params4" ></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab5Root" title="tab5"   [rootParams]="params5" ></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

1. When I click on Search button in the navbar , searchPage appears.
2. Now I  type a name (keyboard appears).
3. On the search page I have another function something like this.

   ionViewDidEnter() {
       this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
       this.navCtrlr.pop();
   }

here , "navbar" in initialised as "@ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;"
and "navCtrlr" is "public navCtrlr: NavController"

4. On click of back I am able to go to tab page again but the here is the problem

a. Before the Tab page displays there is a grey screen appears for fraction of seconds.
b. Tabs a slightly moved towards left , again for fraction of seconds and then again comes to the correct place.

Note:- This all happens only for android platform, neither for ios nor for the browser.